# Register Allocation and Definition of Interference

Tags: compilers

In my textbook on compiler design [[1]](http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/basics_lulu2.pdf), it describes interference between two variables (the property that they cannot be in the same register at once) as follows:

> ***Definition 9.2***:  A variable $x$ interferes with a variable $y$ if $x \neq y$ and there is an instruction $i$ such that $x \in kill[i], y \in out[i]$ and instruction $i$ is not "$x := y$"

This definition does not make sense to me. If I interpret this in plain English:

> A variable interferes with another if some variable $x$ is being overwritten, while some variable $y$ is live at the exit of the instruction, and the instruction is not $x := y$ and $x$ and $y$ have distinct values.

To me, a more logical definition of interference is if two variables $x$ and $y$ appear in the same $gen$ set of some instruction $i$. This necessarily means that these two variables are used (i.e their value) in the same instruction. Is there some crucial detail that I am missing?

For those interested, this definition appears on page 197 of the book referenced above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "reading" of the definition is a little unclear. In particular, it says nothing about the *values* of the variables. Here's a clearer reading:

> A variable $x$ **interferes** with a variable $y$ if 1) they are not the
>   same variable, i.e. a variable never interferes with itself, and 2) there
>   is some instruction other than $x := y$ where $x$ is overwritten while
>   $y$ is live at the end of the instruction (and typically also
>   during, but a multiple assignment instruction like $(x,y):=(a,b)$ would be an example where variables can interfere even though $y$ is not live during the instruction).

As the book points out immediately after that definition, if $x$ and $y$ have the same value (for some stretch of code), then there is no reason they can't be held in the same register (in that stretch of code). This is what makes ignoring $x := y$ instructions valid. The analysis does not calculate the values of anything however. $x$ and $y$ interfere in $\{x := k;y := k; f(x,y)\}$ and so will be assigned different registers. For this analysis to exploit the fact that they have the same value, a prior optimization pass would need to rewrite it to $\{x := k; y := x; f(x,y)\}$.

Your definition is also incorrect. The $gen$ set of $x := k$ is empty, but certainly two variables can't share a register if one is being mutated and the other isn't. Again, as the book points out immediately after the definition, the definition is close to saying that distinct variables $x$ and $y$ can't both be *live* at the same time. (Both being live at the same time would be formulated as $x,y \in out[i]$.) This is a more conservative condition than yours, but it is still incorrect for the same reason. If $x := k$ is the last occurrence of $x$, and thus isn't in the $out$ set of that instruction, it still interferes with $y$.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I think I understand it a lot more now. Just one more question to make sure I understand. If we have an instruction $a=b+c$, then by the definition $a$ and $b$ may interfere with one another, and $a$ and $c$ may interfere with one another, but the definition doesn't handle that $b$ and $c$ perhaps interfere with each other?

Comment: @ReganKoopmans Technically, $a$ and $b$ only interfere if $b$ is live after this instruction. If this is the last occurrence of $b$ then they don't interfere. Similarly for $a$ and $c$. This instruction doesn't give any evidence that $b$ and $c$ interfere with each other. If $b := c$ occurred earlier and no other assignments to either $b$ or $c$ have occurred before the addition instruction, then they don't interfere. Whether $b$ and $c$ interfere requires looking at some other instruction; the addition instruction itself doesn't say either way.

Comment: Two variables either interfere or they don't. It's not a property that varies instruction to instruction. This is why static single assignment (SSA) form is useful. It turns one variable that is assigned to multiple times into multiple variables, one for each live range. If the original variables interfered with each other, then some of these new variables will too, but some may not. This means that while the original variables may not be able to share a register for their entire scope, they may be able to for part of their scope.